# Custom Picker Editor Control

Tags: sharepoint

I have lookup column, but the data in this column is very large.I want to create a custom picker control like (people editor control) in sharepoint.
Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom field type to achieve that.
Information from the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc889345(office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Tom,
Its very help full

Comment: I just found this, it may save you a lot of time:
http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/15633
You can find a lookup column there that already uses the entity picker. You can also find two powershell scripts there, one to convert a lookup column to this custom column and one to do the opposite.